# Arrow that follows SVG path on drag using GSAP

Tags: jquery, svg, gsap

I'm creating a draggable arrow that follows svg path using gsap.

I'm using this codepen as a reference: [CLICK HERE](https://codepen.io/MAW/pen/zGZRqY)

My Development:  [CLICK HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/jimishsoni1990/jc44re7x/3/)

```
var rail = document.getElementById("rail"),
    knob = document.getElementById("knob"),
    H = rail.getBBox().height,
    railLength = rail.getTotalLength();

Draggable.create(document.createElement('div'), {
    type: 'Y',
    throwProps: true,
    bounds: {
        minY: 0,
        maxY: H
    },
    trigger: knob,
    overshootTolerance: 0,
    onDrag: update,
    onThrowUpdate: update
});

function update() {
    var P = rail.getPointAtLength(this.Y / H * railLength);
    TweenLite.set(knob, {
        attr: {
            cx: P.x,
            cy: P.y
        }
    })
};
```

I've changed all X references to Y in my code to make it vertical. 
But doesn't move anymore.

Let me know if any information is require.

Please help.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: rail.getTotalLength is not a function
    at window.onload`

Comment: double click and hold on the second click... moves for me that way.

Comment: @hungerstar Sorry, i added non-updated fiddle version. please check now.

Comment: @ProEvilz it doesn't move for me. :(

Comment: @Jimmy `(index):135 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getPointAtLength' on 'SVGGeometryElement': The provided float value is non-finite.` This is the second time it seems that you've just completely ignored any error messages? Why not look after it being pointed out to you the first time?